# /etc/bash.bashrc Не запускается консоль

Tags: linux, bash

Когда-то знакомый линуксоид поосоветовал мне вместо регулярного экспорта переменных среды через консоль использовать файл `/etc/bash.bashrc`. Я бегло прочитал о нем - "скрипт, который запускается однажды на старте..." - большего мне и не было надо. Я решил, что он выполняется на старте системы, добавил туда экспорт нужных мне переменных, и забыл. Проблема появилась тогда, когда я снова о нем вспомнил и решил поставить на "автозапуск" pidgin и transmission.

Вот тогда я и понял как работает этот файл. После перезапуска компьютера, разумеется, у меня ничего не загрузилось, но загрузилось после открытия консоли. Сама же консоль открывется, но не ожидает ввода. Следовательно, открыть `/ect/bash.bashrc` я не могу, потому что нужны root права, и получаю своеобразный замкнутый круг. Подскажите, есть ли способ как-то поправить наведенный мной хаос?

Comment: зайти под другим пользователем и через sudo поправить

Comment: Все три способа рабочие. (отсебятина: gtk поддерживает получение root прав, что позволяет `gksu redaktor /etc/bash.bashrc`). О, и ещё. Амперсанд (&) после комманды запускает её в фоновом режиме.

Answer (score 3):

Скорее всего, у вас имеется доступ к графической оболочке. В таком случае достаточно просто выполнить команду (через Alt+F2 или подобное, не знаю какая у вас DE)

```
sudo mv /etc/bash.bashrc /etc/bash.bashrc.bck
```

После чего у вас будет доступ к консоли. Далее можно починить файл и вернуть его на место.

Answer (score 3):

Можно прогрузиться с livecd, подмонтировать корень и руками почистить файл.

Answer (score 2):

Если у Вас есть доступ к изменению параметров загрузчика (которым, скорей  всего, является GRUB), то Вы можете указать опцию загрузки для ядра `init=/bin/sh`. Таким образом, прежде запуска системного *init* запустится интерпретатор `/bin/sh` (или соответствующий интерпретатор, на который указывает симлинк `/bin/sh` в вашей ОС). Далее, как было предложено заранее, можно перенести/переименовать/отредактировать файл.

P.S. [Указание опций ядра в загрузчике](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/kernel_parameters#GRUB).